# MySQL Syntax Error - Java

Tags: java, mysql

$You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null, null, null, 98-4B-E1-A9-C5-82, null)' at line 1$

Error that i got when this is executing

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO gameservers" + "VALUES (null, null, null, "+macAddress+", null)");
```

And my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gameservers` (
  `server_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hexid` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `host` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `macAddress` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `firstTime` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`server_id`)
) ;
```

Any idea?

Comment: You should use prepared statements rather than constructing query strings with embedded values via string concatenation: then many of these problems would not occur.

Comment: st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO gameservers " + "VALUES (null, null, null, "+macAddress+", null)"); you are missign a space before VALUES (after table name)

Answer (score 2):

You need a space after gameservers and you need to put macAddress in quotes. At least.

```
"INSERT INTO gameservers " + "VALUES (null, null, null, '"+macAddress+"', null)"
```

Answer (score 1):

macAddress is varchar, so it should be wrapped in **single quote**.

```
"VALUES (null, null, null, '"+macAddress+"', null)"
```

Comment: @user1663856: Don't forget to accept applicable answers. Accepting answers will encourage community to help you.